# How the operator (is) works with tuples and lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

Why when I compare two equal tuples through the operator (is) I get a different result than when I compare two equal lists? (one is True an the other is False)

Nothing really... i am starting with python and i do not want to leave my doubts :)

```
a=(1,2,3)
b=(1,2,3)
c=[1,2,3]
d=[1,2,3]
print(a is b) #True
print(c is d) #false
```

I expected that both were False :(

Comment: C is a list and b is a tuple. What’s wrong with the output? a and b are same

Comment: "I expected that both were False" - well, at least you have a better understanding than if you had expected the results to be True.

Comment: Do you know about "mutability"?

Comment: CPython is able to intern the tuples, but it won't do that for the lists.  There's a dupe somewhere...

Comment: If you're starting out with Python, you're better off forgetting about the `is` operator for a while. Just use `==`, as it's going to be what you want 99% of the time anyway.

Comment: To add to this - the tuples are interned, so they refer to the same point in memory and would be equivalent.

Comment: @Makoto: Given that the questioner expected both results to be False, it sounds like they know what `is` does. This needs a different dupe target.

Comment: @user2357112:  The dupe *does* mention that Python will cache/intern small objects, which is what's happening here, which *does* sufficiently explain OP's case.

Comment: @DanielPryden: I recommend remembering `is` solely for use with `None` early on.

Comment: @Makoto: It only talks about that for integers, without discussing any general principles that would apply to tuples.

Comment: @user2357112:  I mean, if you feel like the dupe is invalid then feel encouraged to cast a reopen vote or edit in a different dupe target.  I'm not a gold badge holder and one is lurking around here, so you'll have a better time appealing to them than me.

Answer (score 0):

Python may optimize small read-only objects (strings, numbers, tuples) by ["interning"](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html?highlight=intern#sys.intern) them (keeping a list of common small objects), or noticing they are the same at compile-time and not making a second copy.

Since these objects can not be changed, this is a safe optimization, and can result in `is` returning True for two objects that would otherwise be separate.

The actual specifics are version specific and can change from release to release.  They are certainly equals (`==`) , but may or may not be the same (`is`).

Lists can be modified (they are `mutable`), therefore, under the current language rules, they have to be viewed as different objects.  They have separate identify and are not `is` the same.  Otherwise changing `c` would change `d`.

Comment: Not really convincing answer.  There is no reason it would be unsafe for CPython to do the same thing for lists (see [CoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)), except that it would probably not be a useful optimization.

Comment: CoW is certainly possible, but `is` is basically the same as id() == id(), and id() is currently defined to be constant for the life of an object.

Comment: Umm... let me right-now "step in, here," and counter-mand your downvote to say that "Max does, in fact, know precisely what he is talking about."  Sometimes there is a world of difference between "(" and "[" ... (I shall leave it to subsequent responders to elaborate.)

Comment: @wim: Copy-on-write would either involve two distinct objects with some shared internals (so `is` would still be false), or major changes to the Python evaluation model and the meaning of `is`.

Comment: Yes, in the CoW case for lists, `is` would be false from the start.  My gripe is that statement: "it would not be be safe to do this optimization", that's just incorrect. Many systems *do* implement this safely. CPython doesn't bother.

Comment: @wim I can try some different verbiage to indicate that lists are modifiable so have to be viewed as separate objects

Comment: Sure.  Or just delete (we don't really need a billionth dupe about CPython interning implementation detail on site IMO)